# JavaScript: Set Content-Type header on Response Object

Tags: javascript, http-headers, fetch-api

How can I set the `Content-Type` header on a `Response` object?

My code so far:

```js
new Response(
    file[1],
    {
        status: 200,

        // i have also tried "contentType", and "ContentType"
        "Content-Type": "text/html",
    },
)
```

For background, I am trying to create a custom HTML file and put it in cache with the caches API, and it is defaulting to text/plain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out right after posting:

```js
new Response(
    "response body here...",
    {
        status: 200,
        headers: new Headers({
            "content-type": "text/html;charset=UTF-8",
        }),
    },
)
```

You need to use the Headers constructor and set it under the "headers" key, then you can set whatever response headers you want.

Comment: For future reference: [`Response()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/Response)